# While statement with Calendar.after doesn't start

Tags: java, calendar, while-loop, comparison

So I've spend a fair amount of Googling and looking through things, but I just can't get it to work. It won't consider the statement as true, even though the request.getEnd() is a couple days after the current startCal.getTime. Any ideas?

```
while(startCal.after(request.getEnd()))
            {
                /* Calculate new beginning */

                startCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                newBegin = startCal.getTime();
                System.out.println(newBegin);
                /* Calculate new ending */

                endCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                newEnd = endCal.getTime();

                /* Setting new dates and series ID */
                localRequest.setBegin(newBegin);
                localRequest.setEnd(newEnd);
                localRequest.setSeriesID(seriesID);

                /* Sending new reservation to database */
                //reserve(localRequest);
                System.out.println("RESERVATION DONE");
            }
```

Comment: can you paste the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better and sooner help

Comment: What is `startCal` and what `request.getEnd()` is returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though the request.getEnd() is a couple days after the current
>   startCal.getTime.

Then it makes sense that it wouldn't start!  This line of code:

```
while(startCal.after(request.getEnd()))
```

Says "While start cal is after request end."  You are describing your data as the opposite!

Comment: Yes you are right. But I checked both already. The code I posted doesn't work with before as well. There is no error message, it just doesn't execute the code inside the while loop. For some reason it must consider the statement as false. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution! Instead of before I used "startCal.getTime().compareTo(request.getEnd()) <= 0". This works just fine! Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

> [`Calendar#after`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after%28java.lang.Object%29) returns whether this Calendar represents a time after the time represented by the specified Object.

So, your code is currently checking whether `startCal` is after `request.getEnd()`, which from your description is the opposite of what you're trying to do.

It would make more sense to use [`Calendar#before`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29) here to get the desired result.